# hashtable with multiple keys in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Following up on my previous question [unordered_map use in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577211/unordered-map-use-in-rcpp), I wish to know if there is a way I can use multiple unique keys with multiple unique values in an unordered_map within Rcpp.

Note: the unordered_map will have two unique keys of string type and two corresponding unique values of string and double type.

Question 1: Please enlighten me if I am wrong with this multiple key-value pair concept of hash table, i.e., if it is even possible to create a hash table like that.

I am trying to do something like this:
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>


using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]

int hash_map()

{
  std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string,std::string>,std::pair<std::string,double>> hashtable3;

  return 0;
}
```

But it gives me the following errors:

[image: See error snapshot below]
Question 2: Do I need to take hint from this example: [C++ unordered_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key), although being someone who is just starting out in Rcpp and C++, I am not sure if I can even implement this in Rcpp, given the fact that exposing C++ classes is something entirely new to me. (I say this as I tried to read through this document [Exposing C++ functions and classes with Rcpp modules](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf), and it was a little overwhelming.

Comment: I think Boost has multi-key hashes, and the BH package should give you that but I do not have an example handy right now...

Comment: And please never ever post screen shots or images.  It really is looked down upon on the site here...

Comment: Cool. Earlier, I tried including boost in my rcpp file, but it gave an error. Can you give me an example how to go about that. Sorry I dont have the error it gave or the command I used. Any pointers will be helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I did not know how else to give the error list as it was too big in the console.

Comment: There are _numerous_ posts about using BH at the Rcpp Gallery.  And numerous questions here.  It is worth learning how to undertake more focused searches.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I will look into it right away.
BTW, I am having a fanboy moment talking to the creator of Rcpp directly.